# When NAS is mounted it becomes owned by root and i cannot change permissions or owner

Tags: permissions, nas

Have a DNS323 NAS which i use for backups. After recent system updates (currently fedora 6.3.5-100.fc37.x86_64) Backups is unable to run as permission is denied to the NAS.
I can change the ownership of the mount point (/mnt/mynas) but after mounting the NAS it becomes owned by root and I cannot change ownership or permissions. Thunar also shows the NAS permissions as owned by root (r/w) and it is marked read only for the group and other users.
I can rename files in sub folders using Dolphin as a normal user but Thunar denies access.
Result of attempting to change ownership below.

```
[root@x570-p mynas]# chown stephen ./
[root@x570-p mynas]# ls -al
total 2052
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     0 Jun  6 16:24 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  4096 Jun  7 11:14 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 46868 Jun  6 15:49 alt-f.log
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 46769 Jun  4 16:45 alt-f.log-previous
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     0 Jun 19  2022 Archive
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     0 Dec  9  2021 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     0 Dec  9  2021 Public
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     0 Mar  9  2022 .Trash-1000
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     0 Dec  9  2021 Users
```

I have checked the file permissions on the NAS and they are set to owned by stephen with r/w access for the group users and all users.
FSTAB entry for the NAS below.

```
/192.168.1.200/Volume_1/  /mnt/mynas cifs vers=2.0,nounix,rw,user=stephen,password=****** 0 0
```

Have tried without the "nounix" but no effect.

Any help or guidance to solve this greatly appreciated.
I am probably missing something simple but searching the forums hasn't provided a solution.

Comment: have you tried adding uid and gid options to set owner of the mounted filesystem as documented in `man mount.cifs`

Comment: Tried setting uid=1000 and gid=1000 but no change. Seems my NAS was accessible normally up until the latest kernel updates, possibly the last 3 as I now can't go back far enough on reboot to get a kernel that works. Just retried again to confirm uid/gic but no change. root still owns NAS and cannot change permissions.

Comment: I feel a bit foolish. <br/>I didn't explicitly unmount the NAS and remount after altering the /etcfstab entry. I mistakenly thought doing a "mount -a" would update the mounting parameters. <br/> Now I have the correct permissions for the NAS and all its folders and files.

Comment: Consider this case closed.

Comment: you could write your own answer :p